# Load classes from current thread and jar

Tags: java, reflection, jar

My goal is in a thread when we reach a method to load some more classes from a jar.How can I set to the current thread a new class loader with the currently loaded class + load some classes from a .jar?

Comment: Is there a reason you can’t include the other .jar file in your classpath?

Comment: Please turn to the [help] to learn how/what to ask here. Just dropping requirements "this is what I want" isn't appreciated. When you try something yourself, and you get stuck with a specific problem, we will gladly help. But please understand that this place is not intended to give guidance with the possibly many steps required to get you from your vision to a working program.

Comment: Use URLClassLoader